# Cannot add Entity Data Model in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I am running Visual Studio 08 Team Edition with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on WinXP.  I am trying to add a Entity Data Model to my project, however, the option to add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" selection does not appear.  To give you a visual, I am essentially following the directions [here](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Introduction-to-the-ADONET-Entity-Framework-using-ASPNET/), but cannot get past step 5 (Right click on project and click Add New Item) because the option to add an EDM does not appear.

Any ideas?  I'm sure I have all of the prerequisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your VS 2008 SP1 installation did not complete successfully. Here are some things to verify:

1. Take a look at http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm and verify if any of the known issues apply in your scenario
2. Open a Visual Studio 2008 SP1 command prompt and type: devenv.exe /setup [ENTER]
3. Repair VS 2008 SP1 from "Add/Remove Programs" or try uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2008 SP1

Comment: It looks like none of the issues apply.  I type devenv.exe /setup but it returns nothing, just a newline and a prompt appears again. Is it supposed to do anything?

Comment: devenv /setup does not display anything, it just restores settings behind the scenes. Have you tried repairing or even reinstalling your VS2008 SP1?

Comment: I just ended up reinstalling VS 08 and SP1...it works now although I'm still curious as to why exactly I couldn't add an EDM.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I had this problem, and reinstalling VS 2008 SP1 fixed it. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that you have:
[Microsoft® Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en)
The important thing to note is the **GDR**. Basically, it's like a service pack. They added some features, like Entity framework.

non-R2 would be ok too. the article you linked above doesn't list this at all, but it's required for entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog post](http://www.wiibart.com/visual-studio-2008-missing-adonet-and-other-p) about the issue.

Essentially, installing VS2008 SP1 (even if the about box on your installation can claim it's already SP1) resolved the issue for me.

Download page for SP1 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=27673c47-b3b5-4c67-bd99-84e525b5ce61&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as described here with VS2012.  I have now installed VS2012 update 2 and this has resolved the issue, so if any one else stumbles upon this for VS2012, try that to fix the issue.